# Windows 10 Groove Music player: Mini version?

Tags: windows-10, groove-music

Windows 10 on PC comes with a new music player application called Groove Music.

In the classic Windows Media Player app that came with prior versions of windows, you could put the UI into a "mini mode" (called a "skin", accessed with the shortcut key Ctrl+2) which could be conveniently placed into a corner of a monitor for at-a-glance data on the currently playing track.

Does the Groove Music app have a "mini mode" like this?  If so, how can it be activated?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, not sure if it does but can be minimised and still play music though but understand what you mean, maybe will come in a future update if not there already.

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid Yep, what I want is to be able to glance at the corner of my monitor and see the name and other basic info about the currently-playing track -- without having the "full" Groove Music window cluttering up my desktop.  Been using Windows Media Player this way for years. Even wrote my own skin: http://www.jonschneider.com/SchneidersEleven.html

Comment: When you play/pause there is a popup window that shows which is sort of like a mini player but the Windows Media style one you've done is good and would be ideal for Groove, something I'd like to see now I think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did, might not be as small as you want but I think you will like it.

Put the mouse on any corner of Groove player and make it as small as possible, and then it will convert to  a small player.

Full size

[image]

Smaller size

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an old one, but what you actually want is the compact mode in Groove.

If you're in the main player window, you want to switch to the playback mode:
[image]

Once there, you want to press on the "Play in mini view" button on the bottom right:
[image]

What you get is a pretty compact player that is always on top!
[image]

You can then make it even smaller or larger by resizing it

Answer (score -1):

Hey man I think I find just what you want on my PC I press FN and F12/11 and a mini form of it pop up it won't last long though but it is small and will show the song name, ETC..