# How do I use the Mini View feature introduced in Windows 10 Creators update?

Tags: windows-10, window, windows-10-v1703

In [Windows 10 Creators Update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/04/11/whats-new-in-the-windows-10-creators-update#attachment_144485), the Mini View feature is introduced:
[image: The Mini View Feature]
I'm particularly interested in this feature, but I don't know how to get it to work. For example, in Groove music, I don't see an option for switching to mini view.
So, how do I use this feature?

<sup>Attribution: Image appears to be copied from
https://winblogs.azureedge.net/win/2017/04/Mini-View.jpg</sup>

Comment: In the absence of an official solution at this time, you can resize the Groove window to be quite small: https://superuser.com/questions/947578/windows-10-groove-music-player-mini-version

Comment: @music2myear Yes, but I can't make it on top of everything without additional software or extension.

Comment: @bertieb: Making trivial changes to closed questions is generally frowned upon.  You should either improve it enough that it qualifies for reopening, or leave it alone.  But, if you do edit a post with image(s) — and especially when your edit is for the sole purpose of inlining the image, and especially when the image is wider than 600 pixels — please use the new (as of a year ago) convention of making the displayed image link to its full-sized version.  (And fix grammar errors, and do other English language improvements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, Mini View only works with the apps *Movies & TV* and *Skype Preview*.

> [How To Switch To Mini View In The Movies & TV App In Windows 10](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/mini-view-in-the-movies-tv-app-windows-10/)
>
> Windows 10 Creators Update has a new feature called Mini View. **It’s
>   limited to the Movies & TV, and Skype Preview apps for now.** ...
>   Microsoft plans to expand this feature to other apps in Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks. I hoped it would work in Groove music so I could see what I am listening to in radio.

Comment: For what it is worth, this feature is not restricted to those two apps (but they might be the only ones currently using it).Third party apps are also able to use it, as it is a documented and supported feature (the feature's internal name is "CompactOverlay"). Third party apps can take advantage of this (if the developers choose to support it), and obviously Microsoft can update their apps to use it too.